# Create (get) a service instance manually Angular 6

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm stuck with an issue where I need to manually create (or better get) an instance of the service without creating a class.

It is a bit of an unusual use case. I have a module for creating dynamic forms. And the form configuration is basically a big JS Object with lots of properties and methods. In one of those methods I need to retrieve some data from a service.

The perfect solution for me (if it existed) would be to manually get the Service instance I need from the Angular DI system with all the deps provided and then call its method. So that I just provide this service in a module and can use it inside that module without the need to create an Injectable class.

It all sounds a bit unclear, I feel. But the thing I wish to do is something like the following:

```
const service: MyService = AngularDI.get(MyService);
```

So that it returns the instance of that service provided in the current module.

===Edit===

Some more explanation of what I actually need.

I have a Service that has multiple dependencies. Those dependencies also have multiple dependencies that are quite complex, etc.

I can not simply create this service via 'new' keyword cuz then I would have to manually initialise all the dependencies and dependencies of dependencies. So, I want Angular DI framework to create this service for me. That's pretty much it.

It feels like a vicious circle - I can't get out from the DI loop where everything has to be either a Component or Injectable and can not be created manually.

Well, for Components, there is a componentFactoryResolver which helps to create them dynamically.. Is there really no such thing for Services?

Comment: So you want to create a class, outside Angular's scope? Why not create an Angular Library (new in Angular 6)?

Comment: did you find a way to do this?. I'm searching for the same